# Does Brave (Zipkin) have support for parallel requests from client to servers

Tags: java, trace, zipkin

I have a distributed system, where a client needs information from multiple sources.

Is there any support for marking parallel processed spans for the same trace in Brave (Java implementation of Zipkin framework)?

Currently, before sending a message I call clientRequestInterceptor.handle(...) and after receiving response clientResponseInterceptor.handle(...), but there is only one instance, so only one span is recorded.

P.S. I found the following project on GitHub that specified that Brave only supports one level of nested client call: https://github.com/leigu/brave-tracer-example. Maybe the same is valid for parallel client calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Brave does not support this. An issue has been reported on their GitHub page. https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/166